# how to take count of array value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There are 3 array ,in this value I have to take count of  _activityStatus :"I" (ony I value) . 
one way i am trying is

```
    StepsStatus :[]

    StepsStatus = StepsVaue.map(StepsVaue => {
          return StepsVaue._activityStatus;
    });
```

I am taking all _activityStatus in StepsStatus . Now I have to take count of I value only .

```
currentNextActivity: Array(3)
    0:
    __typename: "CurrentNextActivity"
    _activityName: "FXL_ACT1"
    _activityStatus: "I"
    _maxHoldTime: "60"
    _userName: "tecnotree"

   1:
    __typename: "CurrentNextActivity"
    _activityName: "FXL_ACT2"
    _activityStatus: "I"
    _maxHoldTime: "60"
    _userName: "tecnotree"
    __proto__: Object

    2:
    __typename: "CurrentNextActivity"
    _activityName: "FXL_ACT3"
    _activityStatus: "N"
    _maxHoldTime: "120"
    _userName: null
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `array.filter()` to create a new array, using only items that match a certain condition.

```
let iValues = StepsVaue.filter((item) => {
   return item._activityStatus === "I"
})

console.log(iValues.length)
```

You may also use `array.reduce()` as Diamond suggested, just remember to define a default value or your result may not be what you expect. :)

```
StepsVaue.reduce((total, item) => total + (item._activityStatus === "I" ? 1 : 0), 0)
```

Comment: could you please help me for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424607/how-to-implement-custom-label-in-stepindicator-in-react-native

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter()` function to filter items.

```
StepsValue.filter(item => item._activityStatus === "I").length
```

Or you can use `reduce()` function

```
StepsValue.reduce((count, item) => count + (item._activityStatus === "I" ? 1 : 0), 0)
```

> I prefer to use `reduce()` because it will use less memory than
>   `filter()`.

Good Luck.